# Docker for Mac with WebStorm Node Remote Interpreter

Tags: docker, webstorm

I'm trying to setup Docker for Mac (beta) to use a full docker environment.

```
Client:
 Version:      1.13.0-rc7
 API version:  1.25
 Go version:   go1.7.3
 Git commit:   48a9e53
 Built:        Fri Jan 13 21:41:57 2017
 OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.13.0-rc7
 API version:  1.25 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.3
 Git commit:   48a9e53
 Built:        Fri Jan 13 21:41:57 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: true
```

Here is my issue. When I go to WebStorm this is what I have:

[image: WebStorm Docker Preference]

I'm able to run and stop `docker run -d -p 80:80 --name webserver nginx` just fine.

What are the steps that I need to get to configure Node.js Remote Interpreter correctly?

[image: WebStorm Node.js Remote Interpreter Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this: https://kawashi.me/docker-integration-in-pycharm-when-using-docker-for-mac.html and it works like a charm. :) I really didn't want to install brew or any extra packages but for this I will make an exception.